# R/Exams - exams2canvas not zipping

Tags: r, r-exams

I am attempting to generate an exam using `exams2canvas()` in R/Exams. It appears that the zip function is not working as it should since it appears the zip file is not being generated in the temp directory for R to move to my desired directory. Instead, I am getting such a message:

```
In file.copy(file.path(test_dir, zipname), dir, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIXJAEv\file11fc433ed06\CLASS_SP20_exam1\CLASS_SP20_exam1.zip to exam_prints\exam1_03-18-2020\CLASS_SP20_exam1.zip:
  No such file or directory
```

Any thoughts on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this means that you don't have a suitable zip program installed. (R/exams should really check for this and throw a better error message.)

The easiest solution on Windows is to install the Rtools from https://CRAN.R-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/. Possibly you need to check the option to include these tools in the search path during the Rtools installation process.

Comment: Thanks! I'm surprised I overlooked this.